# PHP MySQLi execute without bind_param

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

The PHP documentation for **'execute'** includes the **example #2** (https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.execute.php#example-1489) that looks like this :

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare('INSERT INTO myCity (Name, CountryCode, District) VALUES (?,?,?)');

$stmt->execute( ['Stuttgart', 'DEU', 'Baden-Wuerttemberg'] );
```

Notice there is no **`stmt->bind_param`**, the values are added as an array parameter of **`execute`**.

I tried to make this example to work by creating the table and running the code :

```
CREATE TABLE myCity
(
  Name         VARCHAR(99),
  CountryCode  VARCHAR(99),
  District     VARCHAR(99)
) ENGINE=INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET=UTF8MB4 COLLATE=UTF8MB4_UNICODE_CI
```

But it didn't work, nothing was inserted and there was no error message or warning. I also tried using variables instead of static values as parameters of **`execute`** but didn't work either.

Am I missing something? Did I misinterpret the example? So is **`bind_param`** necessary and **`execute`** should not get the values to insert?

I am using PHP version 7.2.18.

Comment: This feature  was added in 8.1.0. See the [Changelog](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.execute.php#refsect1-mysqli-stmt.execute-changelog)

Comment: You can do the desired action with PDO instead of mysqli starting in php version 5.1
https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Binding in execute is only available as of PHP 8.1. If you are running PHP 8.0, passing an extra parameter will throw an error.

If you use PHP 7 or earlier, passing the array as an argument to `execute()` triggers undefined behaviour. That's why you see no errors and it just doesn't work.

It's worth pointing out that this feature was available since PHP 5 in the PDO extension. PDO has more features and is easier to use, so if you don't have a strong need to use mysqli, use PDO instead.